# Indent only first line in multi-line subsection header

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I'm requested that my `subsection` titles look like this:

[image]

However, so far I didn't manage to achieve that. `titlesec` documentation didn't help much. The best I could get is something like this:

[image]

with `\titleformat{\subsection[block]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1ex}{}`. I feel like I could remove indent of the block completely and then add `\parindent` to the title style, but that seems wrong to me.

I would really appreciate any help!

---

*Edit.* I managed to do this in a very ugly way:

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
    {\large\bfseries}
    {\hspace{1cm}\thesubsection}
    {1ex}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{4em}{3em}
```

It somehow does what I need:

[image]

However, I feel bad for doing this. If there is any better way of doing this, it would be very helpful!

Comment: Why would it be bad? In my opinion, it is a valid and good way to do that. And me myself, I would not think about other variant but tweaking `titlesec` like this.

Comment: I don't know, it just doesn't seem right to me. I guess I should deal with it. Also, it's confusing that `\hspace{\parindent}` doesn't work, even though I did `\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, you can use your approach:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
    {\large\bfseries}
    {\hspace{1cm}\thesubsection}
    {1ex}{}
```

but I would like to present you another option, using the `runin` format (for a run-in title) and then, the first mandatory argument of `\titleformat` that allows you to specify (in the `runin` format) the indentation just before the title; a little example using some of your settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate some text for the example

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}[{\\[2em]}]
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{1cm}{4em}{0em}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{Test Subsection with a Long Title that Spans Two Lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]